# Accept only numbers and tab in inputs javascript

Tags: javascript, key

I have some text fields and I want the user to write only numbers and also TAB to go to other inputs easily. I have this javascript code:

```
function validateNumbers(event) {

if(event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57){
  return true;
 }
 return false;        
}
```

And in the HTML I use the attribute **onkeypress** to call the function.

Could you help me with my code to also accept the TAB key please?

Comment: Do you want the text field to accept a decimal value as well?

Comment: Yes, integers and decimals as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tabindex="1"` property in your input tag to specify which input it needs to be focused next using numbers like 1,2 etc.

[Here is an example based on your code](https://jsfiddle.net/zLby6s0h/3/)

Comment: Worked perfectly, but I found out something, the minus sign (-) is now disabled and I cant put negative numbers, how can I solve that little issue? thanks

Comment: You can use `event.charCode == 45` in your if statement. I have updated https://jsfiddle.net/zLby6s0h/8/

Answer (score 1):

be careful this codes was not working in mobile browsers.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txtboxToFilter").keydown(function (e) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
             // Allow: Ctrl+A, Command+A
            (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `keypress`, handle `keydown` and remove all *non-numeric* values

```js
var input = document.querySelectorAll( "input" );

Array.from( input ).forEach( function( el ){
   el.addEventListener( "keyup", validateNumbers );
});

function validateNumbers(event) 
{
    var inputObj = event.currentTarget;
    inputObj.value = inputObj.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
}
```

```html
<input/>

<input/>
```